# Is there a way to fix errata in Rdocumentation.org?

Tags: r, documentation

I use R pretty often and I have noticed that while checking any package's documentation at RDocumentation.org, some pages have errata so I'd like to help fix them if possible. I can't find any way to contact the website team.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe `RDocumentation.org` scrapes its information directly from CRAN/GitHub sources of packages, so it makes more sense to try to contact the package maintainers upstream.

### Contributed packages

- if a package is on GitHub, you can

  - fork the repository, fix the documentation errors yourself, and submit a pull request
  - record a GitHub issue (if there is an open issues list)
  - you might want to check to see if there is a `README` about contributions to see what the maintainers prefer
- if the package is on CRAN, you can go to its CRAN page (e.g. [here](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=bbmle)) and see if there is a development URL or BugReports: field in the description
- if all else fails, the maintainer's e-mail is always available via `maintainer("pkg_name")`

### Base packages

If you find documentation errors in packages that are maintained by R-core (unlikely but possible), you should probably start a discussion on the `r-devel@r-project.org` mailing list. Alternately, you can request write access to the R bug tracker (see [here](https://www.r-project.org/bugs.html)).